# Java/Android: UDP - can't receive larger packets (but still < 64k)

Tags: java, android, networking, udp

I am working on a client-server android application (two applications - one client and one server). The server is expected to send a video to the client over UDP. I am dividing the video into individual frames, each of which end up being about 50,000 bytes, which is theoretically still less than the maximum for UDP.

I am currently testing on two Android emulators running on the same machine, and using UDP port forwarding in between to connect them.

I have set up the UDP such that if I send a byte array of ~5000 or less bytes, it works fine. If I attempt to send my frame byte arrays (50,000 bytes) the application freezes on the DatagramSocket.receive() method on the client.

Is there any way to set it up the UDP transmission to receive a larger byte size?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

But it isn't less than the *practical* maximum for UDP, which is 534 or 576 bytes, can't remember which at the moment, sorry. Whichever it is, that is the largest packet size that will avoid fragmentation. Once a UDP packet is fragmented into N fragments it is N times as likely to be lost.

Comment: If you don't mind clarifying, do you mean to say that UDP is automatically fragmenting packets into ~540 byte segments? I'm not concerned about missing one packet on occasion (since this is a video stream), but right now I can't get any across.

Comment: @user1031648 Any router or host along th path is entitled to fragment any IP packet larger than 534/576/whatever it is. Also, if the packet is larger than the path MTU the sender must do so itself. Path MTU is typically < 1500. So your expectations are several orders of magnitude out.

Comment: There are no routers along the path, however, since this is communicating directly between two android emulators. I've built a similar app with C# that uses a client / server running on the same PC and sends UDP packets of ~50,000 bytes without an issue. Is there something different about UDP on Java/Android relative to C#?

Comment: @user1031648 you may have a coding error as well, or you may be sending to/listening to the wrong ip:port.